# Problem with converting Excel data to python lists

Tags: python, excel, typeerror

Having slight trouble getting an excel import to work - receiving an error as follows:

**TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number**

Have looked at other posts but they don't seem to help.
I can see why there is a problem, just not sure how to fix it... Code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from xlrd import open_workbook

book = open_workbook("Potential_graph.xlsx")
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0) 

variable = []
v1 = []
v2 = []

for row in range(4, 93): #copying data from these cells in Excel columns D, E and F
    variable.append(sheet.cell(row, 3)) 
    v1.append(sheet.cell(row, 4))
    v2.append(sheet.cell(row, 5))


var = np.array(variable)
v_1 = np.array(v1)
v_2 = np.array(v2) 

print v_1

plt.figure()
plt.plot(v_1, v_2)
plt.show()
```

I can see why I get an error, since when I do

```
print v_1
```

I get:

[number:2900.0 number:3045.0 number:2900.0 number:3045.0 number:2936.25
 number:3008.75 number:2954.375 number:2990.625 number:2963.4375
 number:2981.5625 number:2967.96875 number:2977.03125 number:2970.234375
 number:2974.765625 number:2971.3671875 number:2826.3671875]

Basically all I need to know is how to change "number:2900.0" into just 2900.0

Anyone know how this is done?

Comment: that's the exact output you get when you `print (v_1)`?

Comment: Use `sheet.cell_value(...` instead of `sheet.cell(...`

Comment: Sweet yeah that seems to work @stovfl !